# How use Omnipay for Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, configuration, payment

i have the test code, but how i can configure it for payments with paypal?

this is the test code, but if i want do it with paypal? how should i do it?

```
$cardInput = [
        'number'      => '4444333322221111',
        'firstName'   => 'MR. WALTER WHITE',
        'expiryMonth' => '03',
        'expiryYear'  => '16',
        'cvv'         => '333',
    ];

    $card = Omnipay::creditCard($cardInput);
    $response = Omnipay::purchase([
        'amount'    => '100.00',
        'returnUrl' => 'http://bobjones.com/payment/return',
        'cancelUrl' => 'http://bobjones.com/payment/cancel',
        'card'      => $cardInput
    ])->send();

    dd($response->getMessage());
```

Here's documentation: https://github.com/ignited/laravel-omnipay

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you check out the OmniPay [docs](http://omnipay.thephpleague.com/) for questions like this, as it would give you a reference point for how to create payments for different providers.

It's important to note that unless you are in the US, your users will be redirected to PayPal to enter their credit card details etc.

But as an example, it would look something like this:

```
public function postPayment() 
    {
            $params = array(
                    'cancelUrl'     => 'http://localhost/cancel_order',
                    'returnUrl'     => 'http://localhost/payment_success', 
                    'name'      => //Fetch product name,
                    'description'   => //Fetch product description, 
                    'amount'    => //Fetch product price,
                    'currency'  => //Fetch the currency
            );

            Session::put('params', $params);
            Session::save();  

        $gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');
        $gateway->setUsername('paypal account');
        $gateway->setPassword('paypal password');
        $gateway->setSignature('paypal-signature');

        $gateway->setTestMode(true);

        $response = $gateway->purchase($params)->send();
```

From there you would just use the response to determine what to do with the payment.

Whilst written for Laravel 4.2, [this guide](https://solidmarkup.com/blog/using-omnipay-paypal-with-laravel) might help guide you in learning how to use OmniPay.

Comment: What if we need to write unit tests for postPayment() ?